# What is the dual(polar) of $ A := \{ y(.) \in L_1 [0,T]\; |\; y(t) \in C ~ \mbox{for almost all} ~t\in [0 ,T] \} $?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, optimal-control

Let $C$ be  a closed, convex cone in $R^n$. Define 
$$ A := \{ y(.) \in L_1 [0,T]\; |\; y(t) \in C ~ \mbox{for almost all} ~t\in [0 ,T]          \} .$$

My question is that can we derive an explicit formulation for the Dual of $A$ defined by  $$ A^* = \{ z(.) \in L_{\infty} [0,T] \; | \; \langle z , y \rangle = \int z(t) y(t) \;dt \leq 0 \; \text{for all}\; y(.) \in A \} $$

Note that, $A$ is closed convex cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly
$$
\{x\in L^\infty: \ z(t)\in C^* \text{ for almost all } t\} \subset A^*.
$$
Let me show equality. Take $z\in A^*$, $t\in (0,T)$. Let $\chi_{B_r(t)}$ be the characteristic function of the ball $B_r(t)$ for $r>0$ small.

Let $\tilde C\subset C$ be a countable and dense subset. Take $c_i\in \tilde C$.
Define $y(s):= \chi_{B_r(t)}(s)c_i$. Then
$$
0\ge \int y(s)z(s)ds = \int_{B_r(t)} z(s)c_i ds .
$$
By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
we have the convergence
$$
\frac1{|B_r(t)|}\int_{B_r(t)} z(s)c_i ds \to z(t)c_i
$$
for all $t\in [0,T]\setminus N_i$ with $N_i$ being of zero measure. This implies
that for all $i$
$$
z(s)c_i \le 0 \quad \forall s\not\in N_i.
$$
Now, $N:=\cup_iN_i$ has zero measure as well, so
$$
z(s)c_i \le 0 \quad \forall i \text{ and } s\not\in N.
$$
The set $\tilde C$ is dense in $C$, hence
$$
z(s)c \le 0 \quad \forall c\in C \text{ and } s\not\in N.
$$
This implies
$$
z\in \{x\in L^\infty: \ z(t)\in C^* \text{ for almost all } t\} .
$$